# Mysql select in not using index

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a big tables (10M row), with 3 columns : x, y, status.
I have an primary index on x,y.

I request like  '
`SELECT * FROM table where (x,y) in (select 1234,5678)` take approximately 5 secondes
Whereas the request `SELECT * FROM table where (x,y) in (1234,5678)` give the same result for less than 0.01s

I assume it's an issue with indexes, I've tried to add `force index` but without success.

when I run an explain on both query, the first one in not using indexes :

`EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table where (x,y) in (select 1234,5678)`

```
id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | filtered | Extra          |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+----------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | table | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 10794773 |   100.00 | Using where    |
|  2 | SUBQUERY    | NULL  | NULL       | NULL | NULL          | NULL | NULL  | NULL |     NULL |     NULL | No tables used |
```

`EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table where (x,y) in (1234,5678)`

```
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref         | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table | NULL       | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | const,const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-------+
```

Of course I'd like to use the first syntax because the real query is like `UPDATE table set status=123 where (x,y) IN (SELECT x,y from table2 where ... )`;

I really don't understrand this behaviour

Comment: `I assume it's an issue with indexes` - do not assume, check with explain

Comment: More over, you do not need the `select 1234,5678` subquery, use `... in ((1234,5678))` instead (pls note the double parentheses around the values).

Comment: Hi Shadow, you are right, the double parentheses seems to solve my performance issue.  Can you explain what is the purpose of this syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the select 1234,5678 subquery, use ... in ((1234,5678)) instead (pls note the double parentheses around the values):

```
SELECT * FROM table where (x,y) in ((1234,5678))
```

If you check multiple fields with the `in()` operator against a list of constant values, then you need to include the sets of values into parentheses:

```
SELECT * FROM table where (x,y) in ((1,1),(2,3),...(n,m))
```

The above syntax would enable MySQL to match the `x,y` fields against constant values, thus the query can utilise the multi-column index on `x,y` fields.

However, this may not be effective for the `update` query with a subquery. In this case, I would rewrite the `update` with a join instead of a subquery:

```
UPDATE table
    INNER JOIN table2 on table.x=table2.x and table.y=table2.y
    SET table.status=123
    WHERE table2.fieldname=...
```

If `x,y` are indexed in both tables, then the joins should be fast. Moreover, if the table2 indexes are extended to cover the `where` criteria, then such a query can be really fast.